# Is it possible to change the ToolTip text on the run?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox browser overlay, which adds an icon with a tooltip. There is a script that runs onclick and changes the tooltip text, but despite the script seems to be executed, the actual tooltip text does not change at all. Is there a way to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Just for clarification: are you talking about tool tips produced by the title attribute? If so, you'd just need to set the title attribute of the element that's being hovered over.

Comment: Hi, zzzzBov. Thanks for the interest. No, it is about the icon tooltip. When a user clicks the icon the script goes like this:

Comment: MyElement.src = NewImage; MyElement.tooltiptext = "New text"; After this the icon changes but the tooltip does not :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [`tooltipText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/tooltipText) not `tooltiptext`

Comment: Thank you, MatrixFrog, you are a Pro. Darn, it is such a stupid mistake! It works both ways in the XUL document, but JavaScript is so frigging case sensitive. If only there were a debugger that could report such mistakes!

Comment: I use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1815/ and try to keep it open almost all the time while I'm working on things. You *might* get a warning for something like this, but I'm not sure. Good habit anyway, IMHO.